# How to generate a random number with Java from given list of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, random

Assume I have an array/vector of numbers like 1,3,7,9 then I need to guess a number from this list randomly. Using Random class in Java it seems like not possible to do this. Could anyone kindly help me to tell a way to do this kind of thing. I have to change the list of numbers used to generate random number. I am trying to implement a strategy to play battleship game automatically as an assignment. Kindly help me to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the numbers in an ArrayList and use [Collections.shuffle(arrayList);](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List))

Comment: Why take O(N) when O(1) will suffice?

Comment: But in my case I need multiple hits at once. Usually Battleship game played one by one hits, here its changeable at game initialization

Answer (score 18):

If you just want to select *one* random number only, or want to select multiple random numbers with reinsertion (i.e. allow possibility of selecting the same number multiple times), you can generate a random index:

```
List<Integer> lst = ....;
int index = new Random().nextInt(lst.size());
Integer randomeValue = lst.get(index);
```

You can use an array instead as well.  This requires `O(1)` for each selection.

If you need to select multiple distinct random numbers from the list, then using `Collections.shuffle()` and iterating through the list would be a better solution.  This requires `O(n)` for all the queries.

Comment: If you need multiple random numbers then remember to reuse the same Random instance instead of newing one each time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with **tordek** on this one:  Doesn't shuffling seem like a fairly heavy-weight way to select a configured number of random numbers from a source vector?

Wouldn't it be faster to just take **msaeed**'s suggestion for how to pick one random number, and repeat it n times?  Perhaps assemble your random values as a Set, and keep selecting until your set size is big enough... (*don't forget some kind of a check for the edge condition where there's insufficient numbers in the source vector to supply the configured number of random values*)