# how to generate random number from array

Tags: java, arrays, random

How to generate random number from an array? and not from a range.

```
int n [] = {1,7,3,5,8,10,33,12,18}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a random number with Java from given list of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247915/how-to-generate-a-random-number-with-java-from-given-list-of-numbers)

Comment: It isn't clear what this question is asking. Do you want to randomly pick a number from this array, and then return that number?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
import java.util.Random;

...

Random random = new Random();
System.out.println(n[random.nextInt(n.length)]);
```

Comment: Note that you should cache the `Random` instance in a field instead of creating a new instance each time you need a random number.

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, get a random integer ranging from a minimum of 0 to a maximum of the array length -1, and use that as the array index.